# Getting "Step implementation missing" issue in cypress-cumber-preprocessor (cypress version - 13.1.0 and cucumber preprocessor - 4.3.1)

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have installed cucumber preprocessor by using :- npm install --save-dev cypress-cucumber-preprocessor.

Cypress Version :- 13.1.0
Cucumber Preprocessor Version :- 4.3.1

**Below is my folder Structure** :-

```
cypress.config.js

const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress")

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
      on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())
    },
    specPattern: "cypress/e2e/*.feature",
  },
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "cypress_cucumber_bdd",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cypress open"
  },
  "author": "sudeep mahato",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^13.1.0",
    "cypress-iframe": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "chromeWebSecurity": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": false,
    "step-definations": "cypress/e2e/hubspot",
    "cucumberJson": {
      "generate": "true",
      "outputFolder": "cypress/cucumber-json",
      "filePrefix": "",
      "fileSuffix": ".cucumber"
  }
  }
}
```

hubspot.feature

```
Feature: Hubspot user interaction

want to see the demo

    Scenario: User should be able to browse the application
    Given context
    When event
    Then outcome



  hubspotSteps.js

import { Given, When, Then, And } from "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps";
            
            Given("context", ()=>{
                cy.visit('https://www.hubspot.com');
            });
            
            When("event", ()=>{
                cy.get('#hs-eu-confirmation-button').click();
            });
            
            Then("outcome", ()=>{
                cy.get('.hsg-nav__link').eq(3).click();
            });
```

[Config file and folder stracture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLIHy.png)

[JSON file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9FEG.png)

[Feature file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Jff1.png)

[Steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDEVZ.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsAFI.png)

Comment: Please consider changing screens to text, to make it easier to resolve your question.

Comment: Sure. Posting the same query again with detailed description. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The general pattern for step definition matching would be

```js
{
  "stepDefinitions": [
    "cypress/e2e/[filepath]/**/*.{js,ts}",
    "cypress/e2e/[filepath].{js,ts}",
    "cypress/support/step_definitions/**/*.{js,ts}",
  ]
}
```

The `hubspot` part of the feature filename will be substituted into the pattern where the `[filepath]` placeholder is.

You can change up the pattern, but it should include the extension `js` in your case, and wildcards make it easier when you get larger test suites.

Comment: This is actually working now. I am trying to understand the "extension js" for my folder structure a bit more and why it is important to have. Could you please elaborate it more @Aladin Spaz ?

Thanks for the solution again.

Comment: Yes, the documentation says it's using cosmiconfig to use the pattern you give, there is also a link to extra reading.